# Create columns for inherited fields in child-class usine Doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I use Symfony 3. I've got a parent class *Licence* which has some fields:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Licence
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(
 *    type="string",
 *     unique=true,
 *     length=30,
 *     nullable=false
 *     )
 */
protected $licenceKey;
}
```

And I have a child class which extends this one. Surely, it has the same field but I need them to be stored in database in a specific place:
So I wrote the following:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\LicenceCase\FirstLicenceCase;

use AppBundle\Entity\Licence as BaseLicence;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="lic_first")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class FirstLicenceCase extends BaseLicence
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getLicenceKey()
    {
        return $this->licenceKey;
    }
   public function setLicenceKey($licenceKey)
    {
        $this->licenceKey = $licenceKey;
    }
}
```

I need to get the unique columns for any specific LicenceCase. I am going to create new class for every LicenceCase with different fields and methods. But with this code I don't get a proper columns in my database. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You specified class annotations of parent class in the child one. I mean  table and iheritance type. You should just follow the example: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be to specify Inheritance tree where I need to specify all children. e.g in parent class to write the following annotations.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "LicenceCase1", "2" = "LicenceCase2", "3" = "LicenceCase3"})
 */
 abstract class Licence
 {
   // ...
 }
```

This works for me.